White to play and mate in 3 moves..what are the moves?

White to play and mate, moving each of the three pieces exactly once. What are the exact moves?  A puzzle by Henry Dudeney.

The sequence of moves are

 1. Rd6 Kc8 2. Ka7 Kc7 3. Rac6


 After rook d6 the black king is forced to move to c8 then king to a7 black king is forced to go to c7…


The fastest way to checkmate is sacrificing the left rook and bringing the right rook to the 8 rank. But, checkmate in 2 moves would break a rule. If we try to move the rook anywhere else, the black king will just move back and forth on 8a,8b. If we move the king anywhere, black will try to attack the rook. We know any rook placement will lead to stalemate or a game longer then 3 moves. To overcome this, a move needs to made outside the domain it already created. If we move rook to d6 we form a square. If we didn't it will form a smaller square which will forces us to mate in 2 moves.
https://lichess1.org/game/export/gif/white/XRftcpjT.gif?theme=brown&piece=cburnett

Rather than a stream of consciousness paragraph it would be better to use actual chess notation for the moves.  Some line breaks to separate the thoughts would be better as well.

Thank you for the illustration and the details of the 2 move check mate. I really appreciate it. Gave me an insight .
